# Создание рабочей БД SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

[image: Правильно ли я сделал связи?]

Всем доброго времени суток. В общем начал изучать БД, решил создать магазин. Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу разобраться как например сделать связь менеджера и клиента(рис 2).
Так же не могу сообразить как сделать что бы клиенты покупали разные авто.
[image: Тут каждый менеджер продает каждый авто каждому клиенту и так далее]

Comment: а что надо? не понял

Comment: БД работает - значит рабочая.

Comment: Диаграмма запутання, не понятно на ней что с чем связано. Тип связи - видно, а по каким полям - нужно догадываться.

Comment: Угу, а схему состряпал по наитию, подглядывая на потолке... не, так не делают. Начинать изучать надо с теории. Основы проектирования БД, нормальные формы, анализ предметной области, ER-диаграмма... а потом только берись за практику.

Comment: на скриншоте менеджер Анастасия упоминается на каждой дате. на каждом клиенте и так далее.(и так с каждым менеджером), а хотелось бы разобраться как сделать так, что бы она продала к примеру из списка двум клиентам две разные авто, и так же сделать с другими менеджерами.

Comment: Да схему почти так и взял, читаю теорию и по примеру делаю. был один урок по БД, а курсовую нужно сделать вчера) вот и требуется ускоренный режим